# Crossfading slideshow in CSS and HTML

Tags: css

I want to make a crossfading slideshow in CSS.

I am using an example provided by RCNeil 6 years ago in the post “Fading CSS Slideshow without js that loops” which handles 4 images.
I am changing it to handle 9 images.

Since the 4 images in his example are mostly missing I use my own.
Since images in the slideshow are visible but stacked on each other they should have the same size.

I have 8 images (Aride_1.jpg - Aride_8.jpg) to be shown at 7 seconds each. Since I want the last one to be shown for 14 seconds I have just doubled it, added an image Aride_9.jpg which is just a copy of Aride_8.jpg. 
(Is there a better way to choose a specific display time for one image?).

```
Code CSS:

        <style>
        .slide {
            position:absolute;
        }

        .slide:nth-child(1) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 0s infinite;
            -ms-animation: fade 63s 0s infinite;
            z-index:90;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(2) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 7s infinite;
           -ms-animation: fade 63s 7s infinite;
            z-index:80;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(3) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 14s infinite;
           -ms-animation: fade 63s 14s infinite;
            z-index:70;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(4) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 21s infinite; 
             -ms-animation: fade 63s 21s infinite; 
            z-index:60;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(5) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 28s infinite; 
            -ms-animation: fade 63s 28s infinite; 
            z-index:50;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(6) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 35s infinite; 
            -ms-animation: fade 63s 35s infinite;
            z-index:40;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(7) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 42s infinite; 
           -ms-animation: fade 63s 42s infinite; 
            z-index:30;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(8) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 49s infinite;
           -ms-animation: fade 63s 49s infinite;  
            z-index:20;
        }
        .slide:nth-child(9) {
            -webkit-animation: fade 63s 56s infinite; 
            -ms-animation: fade 63s 56s infinite; 
            z-index:10;
        }

        /*  -webkit- Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS browsers:  */
        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
            0%{
              opacity: 1;
           }
           15% {
              opacity: 1;
           }
           25% {
              opacity: 0;
           }
           90% {
              opacity: 0;
           }
           100% {
              opacity:1;
           }
        }

        /*-ms-  Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer:  */
        @-ms-keyframes fade {
            0%{
              opacity: 1;
           }
           15% {
              opacity: 1;
           }
           25% {
              opacity: 0;
           }
           90% {
              opacity: 0;
           }
           100% {
              opacity:1;
           }
        }
      /* For Firefox use similar –moz-,  Old versions of Opera use –o-.*/
        </style>



Code html:

    <body>
    <p style="font-size:30px">CSS Test:</p>
     <div>
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_1.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_2.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_3.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_4.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_5.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_6.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_7.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_8.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    <img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_9.jpg" height="469" class="slide" alt="" >
    </div>
    </body>
```

The result can be seen at http://arxfoto.se/CSSTest.html .

**What are the display times?**

Wanted result is:
Image 1: 7s,  Image 2: 7s,  Image 3: 7 s,  Image 4: 7s,  Image 5: 7s,  Image 6: 7s,  Image 7: 7s,  Image 8(+9): 14s

Actual result is:
Image 1: 11s,
Image 2: 7s,
Image 3: 7s,
Image 4: 7s,
Image 5: 7s,
Image 6: 7s,
Image 7: 7s,
Image 8: 5s,
Image 9: not visible

First image is slightly long and last image is **not displayed at all**. I wonder why?

Could it be affected by the fading that is controlled by this CSS code (??):

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0%{
      opacity: 1;
   }
   15% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   25% {
      opacity: 0;
   }
   90% {
      opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

This Fading Set is chosen by me because it gives a smooth fading. 
But I am not sure whether the percentages in some way must be synchronised with the number of images?

Any pointing in the right direction is very much appreciated!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been obsolete for many years and the `<br>` and `<img>`  tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: Thanks Rob, corrected.

Comment: @vals Thanks for your Answer!! But I am such a newbie and tried to insert my images into your example. 
So I replaced your line “div class="slide">1</div>” with ”<div class="slide"><img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_1.jpg" height="469" alt="" ></div>” etc down to image 8: Aride_8.jpg.

I tested it in http://arxfoto.se/CSSTEst3.html.
But no luck!
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be your code. You can remove all the prefixed styles, they are no longer needed in modern browsers

For the 8th element, you need a separate animation.

And just adjust the delays for every slide

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  animation: fade 63s infinite;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -56s;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -49s;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -42s;
}
.slide:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -35s;
}
.slide:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -28s;
}
.slide:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -21s;
}
.slide:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -14s;
  animation-name: fade2;
}





@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  11% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  13% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
  <div class="slide">7</div>
  <div class="slide">8</div>
</div>
```

About your test. Use devtools, and inspect your elements you will see:

[image: devtools1]

There are only 2 divs

now open them, you get

[image: devtools2]

Notice that the 3rd div with class slide is a child of the second. And there is a "div" element that is just text inside the img ....  This is telling you that your img is bad formed, probably not well closed.

Comment: Thanks vals!! But I am such a newbie and tried to insert my images into your example. 
So I replaced your line “div class="slide">1</div>” with ”<div class="slide"><img src="http://arxfoto.se/images/slideshowTest/Aride_1.jpg" height="469" alt="" ></div>” etc down to image 8: Aride_8.jpg.

I tested it in http://arxfoto.se/CSSTEst3.html.
But no luck!
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have added details about your test in the answer, look at them

Comment: I am so sorry - it was just a typo in my code. See http://arxfoto.se/CSSTest3.html. Works wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Happy that it helped !